# How to configure eml data formatting in splunk

Tags: splunk

I have a large dataset of email(.eml).
And I don't know how to parse and configure sourcetype in splunk.
Please, anyone let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly broad topic so I'll try to cover it at a high level.  Feel free to post more specific questions as you go.

There are a number of things to consider when onboarding a new sourcetype:

1. Where to get the event timestamp?
2. Will each line in the source be a separate event?
3. What separates events?
4. How large are events expected to be?

The answers to these questions help determine the values for the "Magic 6" settings in props.conf.  Those settings are `TIME_PREFIX`, `TIME_FORMAT`, `MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD`, `SHOULD_LINEMERGE`, `LINE_BREAKER`, and `TRUNCATE`.  In this case, I would also add `DATETIME_CONFIG`.

Since the individual lines in a .eml file do not contain timestamps, you can skip the timestamp-related settings and use `DATETIME_CONFIG = none`.  The other settings depend on how you answer questions 2-4.